# Send X-Auth token as callout header

Tags: callout

I need to send an X-Auth token to a external web service, the documentation for the web service shows

```
curl -v -H X-auth-token: DGKJSJ2K71Q88RHLVWJSMH9ZKRQXXXXX http://localhost:3000/twig-node/v1/vault/4rvrP_0IPZ_gQKjAVgMQaA==
```

I know the -v is verbose and I don't need that and that the stuff following -H is the header, I've written an http request to try and simulate the curl but I'm getting system.calloutexception Invalid header.

```
       HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res1 = new HttpResponse();
    Http http1 = new Http();

    req1.setMethod('POST' ); // Method Type
    req1.setEndpoint('https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/node');
    req1.setheader('X-auth-token: ' , Usermap.get('xAuth'));
    string bodyrequest = '';
```

Anyone know how I can get it to send the header I need? Thanks

Comment: Have you added system.debug statements to make certain your Usermap.get('xAuth') is returning a value? You may also want to see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm.

Comment: @crmprogdev I can see the value being returned in the debug log, I found the reason for the error, setHeader is (key) (string) and only supports standards approved header keys.  I eventually resolved the issue by having the people who wrote the api accept 'Authorization' instead of 'X-auth-token: '  Salesforce need to add a way to set custom header keys.